# Come to the dark side, we have cookies?

Tags: star-wars, meme

Where does this come from? Obviously the first half is from Star Wars but the expression is not from *Spaceballs* and some Googling doesn't find anything.

Comment: [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/come-to-the-dark-side) gives no help.

Comment: https://davidmperez.wordpress.com/2007/09/04/where-come-to-the-dark-side-we-have-cookies-comes-from/#comment-46

Comment: The Straight Dope message boards trace it back to 1997 at least. http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=686007

Comment: Good question! This [has been](http://kiops.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/where-come-to-dark-side-we-have-cookies.html) asked [before](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=686007) on the web, but apparently nobody knows the answer.

Comment: Maybe it's a variation on 'the cake is a lie'?

Comment: @Neeshka: It *far* predates that reference. :)

Comment: At a guess, it comes from the various promotional events that use cookies to entice customers.

Comment: [Come upstairs. We have cookies.](http://prairiehome.publicradio.org/programs/19971220/971220_DARK.shtml)

Comment: Does that have to come from somewhere? Cookies are often used as enticement.

Comment: I remember seeing this maybe ten years ago on a t-shirt - but I doubt that is the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mallrats (the movie) they refer to smoking pot as 'the dark side' using a stars wars reference which could bridge the gap between vader and cookies...

Comment: And there's a "Time for cookies" place in the food court. This is a very interesting theory.

Answer (score 1):

I was using "Join the Dark Side, win a cookie!" as my tagline in the Star Wars chatroom, Cloud City Cantina (www.outpost10f.com) from September 1999, and I have yet to see an earlier reference. I used the handle Darth Sidious, and when I log in on occasion, I still use this tagline.

The other "Sith" of the chat would then tempt new members with, "Join us! We have cookies!" and I have reason to believe that it may have stemmed from there.

I stopped regularly chatting there in about 2005, and the earliest reference I can find to it otherwise is about 2006.

So...yay me? :D :p

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  That's really neat; is that archived somewhere for posterity?

Comment: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showpost.php?p=18769500&postcount=36 "A quick search of Google N gram turns up an example from 1992."